# Thumbnail when posting links (like facebook's)

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to know how can I create a thumbnail with a preview image from a link of an external website (like the preview image when you post a link on Facebook or WhatsApp)?

I tried to use CURL, but I got cross-domain restriction.

Anyone knows how to do this without the cross-domain restriction?

(I'm trying to pick an image of the product when posting a link from a clothe of a department store)

**Edit:**

What i'm trying to do is this:

[image]

Whatsapp gets an image when you post a link

I don't have the curl code that got cross-domain restriction because it was from another project, but with the same concept. 
I added javascript on the tags because both facebook and  whatsapp generates the preview in client side

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have curl, and PHP's curl wouldn't be subject to cross-domain restrictions. Can you show what you attempted, please?

Answer (score -2):

That's too easy to even ask. You need to make use of the open graph protocol, it is actually created by Facebook if I'm not mistaken.

In order to have a preview of any of your articles you will have to put them in the head section of your template. Once online and once shared by you or any other user, it will automatically show the preview.

Regards

[Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: I think you've got things backwards. OP appears to be asking how to *read* OG tags, so they can do the same sort of thing Facebook does.

Comment: well, I may have not read it well but still the only way as FAR as I know when sharing any type of content from your website to any different website (or viceversa; called "external" as well) is by making sure X-website has those open graphs, other than that I don't see any other way aroun and reinventing the wheel is mostly seen as bad practice.

Comment: Again, you're looking at this from the wrong side of things. Open Graph tags are necessary to get Facebook to show a preview correctly. OP isn't asking how to do that - they're asking how to *read* **other site's** open graph tags to fetch and display the preview image on **their own site**.

Comment: That's what the open grpah does!. You don't need to do any extra stuff in order to display the corresponding values from the **external** website to your **own** website, otherwise sharing content from the external website to yours will result in sharing your own content(let's put it that way as it would end up reading your own open graphs).... but that's not the case as long as the external website has its own as well.

Comment: OP is looking for code that will **fetch** `example.com`'s Open Graph tags so they can display the data. This'll require something like cURL and a HTML parser (or regex, but that's not ideal).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i'm trying to preview others website links on my site